# Call a function from a If conditional

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to call range-check in an if conditional inside a function called add-check.

 You can find range-check below:

```
;;; range-check takes 4 arguments:  row, numrows, col, numcols It checks if
;;;  0 <= row < numrows and similarly for col and numcols.  If both row and col are in 
;;;  range, range-check returns #t.  If either are out of range, rangecheck  returns #f
(define (range-check row numrows col numcols)
  (not (or (< row 0) (< col 0) (>= row numrows) (>= col numcols))))
```

Func is function of rows and columns. Numrows and numcols are a number.
I am trying to call range check under the function add-check below.

- If range check returns true, I want to return the two numbers of func
- If it returns false, I want to print a period character

This is add check:

```
(define (add-check func numrows numcols)
   (if((range-check? (car func) numrows (cdr func) numcols)))
     (cons '((car (func)) (cdr (func))))
     #\.)
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
if: bad syntax in: (if ((range-check? (car func) numrows (cdr func) numcols)))
```

which I'm assuming implies an error in the if condition.


I'm positive I'm making a silly syntax issue or multiple syntax issues. I'm new to scheme and this IS for a school project. So please help to whatever capacity you can.

Comment: From the indentation it looks like you intended the `cons` and the `#\.` to be within the `if`, right? If that's what you meant then you have an extra closing paren at the end of the line with the `if`. That extra closing paren makes it think the `cons` and `#\.` come separately after the `if` is done

Comment: @AlexKnauth, I am trying to return the cons if the IF condition is true, ELSE  return #\.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
(define (range-check? row numrows col numcols)
  (not (or (< row 0) (< col 0) (>= row numrows) (>= col numcols))))

(define (add-check func numrows numcols)
  (if (range-check? (car (func)) numrows (cdr (func)) numcols)
      (cons (car (func)) (cdr (func)))
      #\.))
```

1. I guess that you forgot to call `func` in `(range-check? (car func)...)`.
2. You forgot `?` in `range-check`.
3. You have extra function call around `(range-check....)` which is definitely wrong since `range-check?` returns a boolean which is not callable.
4. `if` should have then and else branches inside its parentheses,
5. `(cons '((car (func)) (cdr (func))))` is wrong. `cons` consumes two arguments, but you provide one, which is a quoted expression. I assume that they should be `(car (func))` and `(cdr (func))`.
6. If possible, use DrRacket. You can select all and indent, which will reveal some of these mistakes easily.
7. Another way to write `range-check?` more concisely: `(and (< -1 row numrows) (< -1 col numcols))`.
8. You might want to consider calling `func` just once and bind its result to a variable, and use that variable instead. In case `func` is expensive, doing so will make your code more efficient.
9. You can simplify `(cons (car (func)) (cdr (func)))` to just `(func)`!

Comment: Wow... thanks so much! I appreciate it. Unfortunately, range-check is code written by the professor. So I'm assuming he might have done it incorrectly lol. I'll ask him about these things Will try and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

args is not clear, I guess what you want , this is my version:

```
#lang racket

(define (range-check? row numrows col numcols)
  (not (or (< row 0) (< col 0) (>= row numrows) (>= col numcols))))

(define (some-func row col)
  (format "row:~a col:~a" row col))

(define (add-check rowandcol numrows numcols num-func)
   (if (range-check? (car rowandcol) numrows (cdr rowandcol) numcols)
     (num-func (car rowandcol) (cdr rowandcol))
     #\.))

(add-check '(1 . 2) 10 10 some-func)

(add-check '(1 . 2) 1 1 some-func)

(add-check '(1 . 2) 2 3 (lambda (num col) #t))
```